# Laravel submit button

Tags: php, laravel

I have two subscribe forms, one in the main page, other in the footer. They both have the same callback function but the one in the footer doesn't trigger the script.

```
<footer id="main-footer">
    ...
    <form method="post" action="/subscribe" id="subscribe-form-footer">
        ...
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="-------" data-callback='onSubmitFooter'>{{trans('content.input_submit')}}</button>

    </form>
</footer>
```

I tried placing the script in the head of the document, inside footer tags, at the end of footer tags, but it just isn't triggering it. Here is the script:

```
<script>
    function onSubmitFooter(token) {
        document.getElementById("subscribe-form-footer").submit();
    }
</script>
```

**EDIT:**

Even though thanks to [Prasad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/787669/prasad) I corrected the ID, the problem still persists wherever I put the script.

Comment: change script to `document.getElementById("subscribe-form-footer").submit();`

Answer (score 3):

Use below one. In your case id is not correct

```
  <script>
        function onSubmitFooter(token) {
            document.getElementById("subscribe-form-footer").submit();
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

So the first issue is solved in the answer of @prasad.

The second issue that you're having now is the following:
The script is called upon in the right way but still won't run. First of all i can see that you're using `google recapthca`. Since you're telling us you're using two forms on one page this is the problem.

`Google recapthca` doesn't normally support two buttons on one page with the same

```
data-sitekey="-------"
```

When this does occur one of the scripts won't work correctly if you don't make some adjustments.

See the example below:

```js
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=myCallBack&render=explicit" async defer></script>
    <script>
      var recaptcha1;
      var recaptcha2;
      var myCallBack = function() {
        //Render the recaptcha1 on the element with ID "recaptcha1"
        recaptcha1 = grecaptcha.render('recaptcha1', {
          'sitekey' : '6Lc_0f4SAAAAAF9ZA', //Replace this with your Site key
          'theme' : 'light'
        });
        
        //Render the recaptcha2 on the element with ID "recaptcha2"
        recaptcha2 = grecaptcha.render('recaptcha2', {
          'sitekey' : '6Lc_0f4SAAAAAF9ZA', //Replace this with your Site key
          'theme' : 'dark'
        });
      };
    </script>
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <div class="col-md-6">
          <form class="form-signin" role="form" action="validateform.php" method="POST">
                <div id="status">
                </div>
            <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
            <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
            <input type="email" id="inputEmail" value="mycodde@test.com" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>
            <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
            <input type="password" id="inputPassword" value="rashid" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
            <div id="recaptcha1"></div>
            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
          </form>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
          <form class="form-signin" role="form" action="validateform.php" method="POST">
                <div id="status">
                </div>
            <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Sign Up Form</h2>
            <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
            <input type="email" id="inputEmail" value="mycodde@test.com" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>
            <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
            <input type="password" id="inputPassword" value="rashid" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
        <div id="recaptcha2"></div>
            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
          </form>
      </div>
    </div> <!-- /container -->
```

NO! This example doesn't work here because of some missing requirements but it does show how to configure 2 `google recaptcha` buttons on one page. By adding two different `id's` and calling both of them in the `js` as a variable the scripts won't collide with eachother.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The problem is that function doesn't get triggered at all, as if my callback is wrong. Even if I try to print out to console, I get nothing on click with new sitekey added to another button.

Comment: You don't need to change the site key. But the id needs to be changed @Norgul The example code makes use of one `sitekey` but different `id`'s and `variables`. have you tried that?

Comment: I didn't, because your solution uses classic reCaptcha, mine uses invisible one, and I don't want it rendered, I want it attached to a button. But even without that, if I delete first button, second one never triggers the function. It's like it is ignoring the script while under `<footer>` tag...

Comment: alright. Then the issue should be in between the two forms. The footer form should be different from the normal form since one works and the other doesn't. You should compare the two forms very good. look at things such as the `<form>` tag attributes and the `<button>` attributes. And does the `<form action="..."` work on both? etc.

Comment: It should be a JS issue or something because when I convert it to a classical button with type submit, it submits normally

Comment: `(token)` Since you're submitting content or atleast the filled in requirements. the token should be the `CSRF_token` i presume? or did you forget to put that into the form?

Comment: I removed the token, calling empty function...nothing. CSRF is posted on both forms btw

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145634/discussion-between-deathstorm-and-norgul).